# I have problem keeping old data in SQL spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have already released my app in the app store and the database version was 8, but there is a problem. The database has already updated to version 10 and has already added new columns, but now I can't recover old data and this will hurt users a lot. So I wish you a useful solution that does not delete the previous data
Thank you

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String DB_BALL = "ball.db";


public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DB_BALL, null, 10);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table volleyball_db "+ "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, team_a TEXT ,goals_a TEXT," +
            " team_b TEXT, goals_b TEXT, round TEXT, date_volleyball TEXT, clock_volleyball TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("create table basketball_db "+ "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, team_a TEXT ,goals_a TEXT," +
            " team_b TEXT, goals_b TEXT, round TEXT, date_basketball TEXT,clock_basketball TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("create table football_db "+ "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, team_a TEXT ,goals_a TEXT, card_red_a TEXT, card_yellow_a TEXT," +
            " team_b TEXT, goals_b TEXT , card_red_b TEXT, card_yellow_b TEXT, round TEXT, date_football TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS volleyball_db ");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS basketball_db ");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS football_db ");

    onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: Can you do ALTER TABLE instead of doing DROP/CREATE?

Answer (score 1):

Once the database tables have been dropped, you cannot recover the data. you should use `ALTER TABLE` to update the tables

Comment: You did what you told me, but this error occurs                                                 
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: volleyball_2_db (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE volleyball_2_db ADD COLUMN clock_volleyball string;, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

Comment: Because I already added the new column in the last issue, before I do this method, my problem now is I don't want to delete the previous data for the older versions